# create child team area in an existing team area

Tags: rtc

I can create child team areas while creating new team areas but I also want to create child team area to an already existing team using plain java API.

I think we need to have project area working copy for this but then  I am not getting the method `getTeamAreaHierarchy()` with that in the method list.

```
teamArea2 = (ITeamArea)ta.teamRepository.itemManager().fetchCompleteItem(TAHandle,IItemManager.DEFAULT,monitor);
IProcessAreaWorkingCopy areaWc = (IProcessAreaWorkingCopy)service.getWorkingCopyManager().createPrivateWorkingCopy(teamArea2);
```

But I don't find `getTeamAreaHierarchy()` method when  I do '`areaWC.`' (not getting the method after the dot).

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

From [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/114726/how-to-create-teamarea-hierarchy-using-rtc-api), `getTeamAreaHierarchy()` would be a method of `ITeamAreaHierarchy`, which differs from `IProcessAreaWorkingCopy`.

Check if that method is available on your `ITeamArea teamArea2` variable instead.

From [your new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18004211/6309), I guess this had to work:

```
ITeamArea TA = (ITeamArea)teamRepository.itemManager().fetchCompleteItem(newTAHandle,ItemManager.DEFAULT,monitor);
IProcessAreaWorkingCopy areaWc = (IProcessAreaWorkingCopy)service.getWorkingCopyManager().createPrivateWorkingCopy(TA);
```

Comment: Not neccessary this is true. While creating child team area I did this and it worked. projectarea.getTeamAreaHierarchy().addChild(teamArea,childteamArea); I just need to get the project area working copy correctly and it should resolve my issue.

Comment: @KaushambiSuyal I agree, but in your case, a `ProcessArea` isn't then same than a `ProjectArea`. `getTeamAreaHierarchy` should be available on a `ProjectArea` or `TeamArea`, not `ProcessArea`.

Comment: ok..what can be done to do this..I mean the project area working copy?

Comment: @KaushambiSuyal can you cast `areaWC` in a `IProjectAreaWorkingCopy`  instead of a `IProcessAreaWorkingCopy`, and see if that works better? (see if `getTeamAreaHierarchy` is available there?)

Comment: I did that try too but didn't work. can you check if I am doing this correctly, the declaration of project area working copy. IProjectAreaWorkingCopy pwc = (IProjectAreaWorkingCopy)service.getWorkingCopyManager().createPrivateWorkingCopy(teamArea2); ((IProjectArea) pwc.getTeam()).getTeamAreaHierarchy().addChild(teamArea2,childteamArea);

Comment: @KaushambiSuyal Note that https://jazz.net/forum/questions/41029/rtc-api#41038 seems to say that IProjectArea and ITeamArea extend IProcessArea anyway. https://jazz.net/forum/questions/108171/get-teamarealist-attribute-with-rtc-java-api gets a project area in a more straightaway way.