# How to add users and roles in child team area using plain Java RTC API?

Tags: rtc

Is it possible to add users and roles in child team area? My code currently can add users and roles in team areas but how can I add them in child team area.

```
ITeamArea TA = (ITeamArea)teamRepository.itemManager().fetchCompleteItem(newTAHandle,ItemManager.DEFAULT,monitor);
 IContributor contributor = teamRepository.contributorManager().fetchContributorByUserId(members,monitor);
 ArrayList roles  = getTeamRoleName(projectArea,member_roles);
 IProcessAreaWorkingCopy areaWc = (IProcessAreaWorkingCopy)service.getWorkingCopyManager().createPrivateWorkingCopy(TA);  
 areaWc.getTeam().addContributorsSettingRoleCast( new IContributor[] {contributor}, new IRole[] {roles})); 
 areaWc.save(null);
```

I was trying to find the hierarchy stuff, but then not finding the option of adding contributors to child team area.

```
IProjectArea workinCopyProjectArea = (IProjectArea) projectArea.getWorkingCopy();
            ITeamAreaHierarchy teamAreaHierarchy = (TeamAreaHierarchy) workinCopyProjectArea.getTeamAreaHierarchy();
```

Answer (score 0):

That  `projectArea.getWorkingCopy();` was described as *not* working in [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/62667/add-user-to-project-area).

While this was:

```
ProjectAreaWorkingCopy wc = new ProjectAreaWorkingCopy(projectArea);
wc.addMembers(c);
```